# How to count work days between date columns with Polars

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

[image]

Assume there are two columns name `date` and `maturity_date` in a Polars DataFrame, they are both the type `pl.Date`. If use `pl.col("maturity_date") - pl.col("date")` we could get the diff days.

But how to get the numdays of the workdays between `date` and `maturity_date`(not count saturday and sunday)?

Or even calculate diff days that use a given calendar like a trade date calendar of stock market which is different from a normal calendar.

Use `pl.concat_list([pl.col("date"), pl.col("maturity_date")]).apply(func)` to call a udf python func could work, but this would be slow.

[update]

```py
data = pl.DataFrame( [ pl.Series("date", [datetime.date(2000, 1, 4), datetime.date(2000, 1, 4), datetime.date(2000, 1, 4), datetime.date(2000, 1, 4), datetime.date(2000, 1, 4)], dtype=pl.Date), pl.Series("maturity_date", [datetime.date(2000, 1, 17), datetime.date(2000, 2, 15), datetime.date(2000, 3, 15), datetime.date(2000, 4, 17), datetime.date(2000, 5, 15)], dtype=pl.Date), ] )

data.with_columns(
    pl.date_ranges(e.date, e.maturity_date, closed="both", eager=False)
    .list.eval(pl.element().dt.weekday() <= 5)
    .list.count_match(True)
    .alias("duration")
        
    # pl.concat_list(["date", "maturity_date"]).apply(lambda x: get_work_days(x[0], x[1]))
    # .alias("duration")
)
```

I use this date_ranges to count, but it seems only a little faster than apply

Comment: If you can make a list of dates that don't count then do a date_range on begin and end dates instead of subtraction. From that generated list exclude elements which are in the initial list. Lastly, do a count on the remaining elements of the new filtered list.

Comment: Please don't post screen captures, paste the output of `print(df.to_init_repr())` instead

Comment: pl.DataFrame(
    [
        pl.Series("date", [datetime.date(2000, 1, 4), datetime.date(2000, 1, 4), datetime.date(2000, 1, 4), datetime.date(2000, 1, 4), datetime.date(2000, 1, 4)], dtype=pl.Date),
        pl.Series("maturity_date", [datetime.date(2000, 1, 17), datetime.date(2000, 2, 15), datetime.date(2000, 3, 15), datetime.date(2000, 4, 17), datetime.date(2000, 5, 15)], dtype=pl.Date),
    ]
)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Dean MacGregor's excellent answer using pure Polars wasn't quite performant enough for my use case.
Using Numpy's built in `busday_count` function turned out to be much faster in my case and can easily be converted back to a polars with `pl.from_numpy`.

```
nyse_holidays=pl.Series([
    date(2000,1,17),
    date(2000,2,21),
    date(2000,4,21),
    date(2000,5,29),
    date(2000,7,4),
    date(2000,9,4),
    date(2000,11,23),
    date(2000,12,25),
])
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "business_days": pl.from_numpy(np.busday_count(data["date"], data["maturity_date"]),["business_days"])["business_days"],
        "trade_days": pl.from_numpy(np.busday_count(data["date"], data["maturity_date"], holidays=nyse_holidays),["trade_days"])["trade_days"],
    }
)
shape: (5, 2)
┌───────────────┬────────────┐
│ business_days ┆ trade_days │
│ ---           ┆ ---        │
│ i64           ┆ i64        │
╞═══════════════╪════════════╡
│ 9             ┆ 9          │
│ 30            ┆ 29         │
│ 51            ┆ 49         │
│ 74            ┆ 72         │
│ 94            ┆ 91         │
└───────────────┴────────────┘
```

Comment: much faster version， thank you！

Comment: There's now a Polars solution which works with the lazy API, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/77381105/4451315

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate things going on. The first is to exclude Saturdays and Sundays and then also excluding a list of holidays.

Let's say we have

```
from datetime import datetime, date
nyse_holidays=pl.Series([
    date(2000,1,17),
    date(2000,2,21),
    date(2000,4,21),
    date(2000,5,29),
    date(2000,7,4),
    date(2000,9,4),
    date(2000,11,23),
    date(2000,12,25),
])
```

We can also generate a Series of weekends

```
weekends=(
    data.select(
        weekends=pl.date_ranges(
            pl.col('date').min(), 
            pl.col('maturity_date').max(), closed='both', eager=False)
        .explode()
    )
    .filter(pl.col('weekends').dt.weekday()>5)
    .get_column('weekends')
)
```

Putting that together we can do...

```
(data.with_columns(
    normal_diff = (pl.col('maturity_date')-pl.col('date')).dt.days(),
    
    norm_diff_count=pl.date_ranges(
        pl.col('date'), pl.col('maturity_date'), closed="right", eager=False
    )
    .list.lengths(),
    
    workdays_diff=pl.date_ranges(
        pl.col('date'), pl.col('maturity_date'), closed="right", eager=False
    )
    .list.set_difference(pl.lit(weekends).implode())
    .list.lengths(),
    
    tradedate_diff=pl.date_ranges(
        pl.col('date'), pl.col('maturity_date'), closed="right", eager=False
    )
    .list.set_difference(pl.lit(weekends).implode())
    .list.set_difference(pl.lit(nyse_holidays).implode())
    .list.lengths(),
    
    
))
shape: (5, 6)
┌────────────┬───────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────────┬───────────────┬────────────────┐
│ date       ┆ maturity_date ┆ normal_diff ┆ norm_diff_count ┆ workdays_diff ┆ tradedate_diff │
│ ---        ┆ ---           ┆ ---         ┆ ---             ┆ ---           ┆ ---            │
│ date       ┆ date          ┆ i64         ┆ u32             ┆ u32           ┆ u32            │
╞════════════╪═══════════════╪═════════════╪═════════════════╪═══════════════╪════════════════╡
│ 2000-01-04 ┆ 2000-01-17    ┆ 13          ┆ 13              ┆ 9             ┆ 8              │
│ 2000-01-04 ┆ 2000-02-15    ┆ 42          ┆ 42              ┆ 30            ┆ 29             │
│ 2000-01-04 ┆ 2000-03-15    ┆ 71          ┆ 71              ┆ 51            ┆ 49             │
│ 2000-01-04 ┆ 2000-04-17    ┆ 104         ┆ 104             ┆ 74            ┆ 72             │
│ 2000-01-04 ┆ 2000-05-15    ┆ 132         ┆ 132             ┆ 94            ┆ 91             │
└────────────┴───────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────────┴───────────────┴────────────────┘
```

You'll notice that your workdays_diff and mine are off by 1. I would argue that you're either overcounting there or undercounting in normal_diff by 1. I added an extra norm_diff_count column above to illustrate that closed="right" (or maybe "left") is what you want rather than "both" if your normal_diff is using `maturity_date-date`.

I have no idea how you're coming up with what you have in tradedate_diff so I can't comment on that difference. Maybe you're using a bigger holidays list than what I found for NYSE holidays.

Answer (score 1):

You can now do this within Polars, you'll just need the [polars-xdt](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars-xdt) plugin

This is fast and works in lazy execution

Assuming `nyse_holidays` is a list of `date`s

```py
import polars_xdt as xdt

data.with_columns(
    result = xdt.workday_count(
        'date',
        'maturity_date', 
        holidays=nyse_holidays,
    )
)
```